# Failed when trying to run pipelines on Azure DevOps

Tags: node.js, macos, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an error whenever I try to run the pipeline using node.js with React:

> [error]Bash exited with code '1'.

Here is the full log:

https://dev.azure.com/M-72010/99e99521-6f3f-42f9-a2d8-009f77a3608c/_apis/build/builds/9/logs/7

I am looking forward to getting help from you.

Thanks very much

Comment: The error is Failed to find .env file at default paths: [./.env,./.env.js,./.env.json], you should check the path and ensure the file exists.

Comment: How can I locate the .env file and add it to azure DevOps pipelines?

Comment: Hi iMohammad,
The file should be in your repo, you need check the path and ensure the file exists, in the pipeline, it will check the path and load the file.

Comment: Hi iMohammad,
I also found a [similar issue](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd/issues/92), and there are some workaround in that ticket, please also try it and kindly share the result here.